# Replace Windows Explorer or File Explorer with Other Third Party Explorer (i.e., Clover, Groupy, Explorer++ etc.) in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm using third party Explorer for long. However, very recently (2020 H2 windows-10 update), I started to notice that, when I'm opening some files (for example, I downloaded a document with Chrome and want to find out/see the file), windows-10 native windows/file Explorer is opening the file location window instead of my other Explorers (i.e, Clover, Groupy, Files, Total Commander etc.). If I can't use one of these Explorers as my default Explorer, replacing the windows file Explorer, my point is why should I even use these third party Explorer in the first place! Is there any way to replace the native Windows Explorer with third party Explorer?
Read about clover explorer here: https://www.guidingtech.com/50967/chrome-styled-tabbed-interface-windows-10/

My point is that: I DO NOT want windows file explorer as a default explorer but a third party explorer (i.e. Clover) as default. How do I do that?

I'm a non-techy user, so, simple guidance is requested. Thanks!

Comment: Unclear: Why would Explorer come up when you are *opening a file*? What kind of file? How are you opening it?

Comment: Before opening a file, first I need to open the drive location which opens a window through Windows Explorer. Then I need to click to open the file- isn't it? My intention is to open the Window through 3rd party Explorer; not with the Windows Explorer. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: After downloading in Chrome, the file can be opened directly from the download bar at the bottom, or from the downloads list (Ctrl+J), without the need for Explorer.

Comment: I know. But, for many cases, I need to get to the explorer to see the actual file..cut-copy-paste it... and the download example I gave is just one use case. My main point is that: I DO NOT want windows file explorer as a default explorer but a third party explorer (i.e. Clover) as default. How do I do that?

Comment: So the question is: with what action do you open the path? It might be possible to change the result of the action.

Comment: So, how I to do that? You may also see this. Since I'm also seeking similar support: https://www.sevenforums.com/customization/152674-how-change-default-file-manager.html

Comment: For the third time: How do you open the drive location? What do you click on, or what hotkey do you use and in which application?

Comment: Just help me to set Clover explorer as my default file manager...currently windows explorer is default, which I do not like.